# Node js and ejs using loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express, ejs

I am new to node.js and now I am facing a problem with EJS template. I noticed my `for` loop is not running though the EJS template. I tried to make a very basic todo app.

**Here is the hierarchy of the project I made**

[This is my project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgEHT.png)

**This is my App js module**

```
let express = require('express');
let todoController = require('./Controller/todoController')
let app = express()
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
todoController(app);




app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log('server started on http://localhost:3000');
})
```

**todoController.js**

```
 let toDoList = ['Go to university','Smoking sigrate'];
    module.exports= function(app){
        app.get('/', function(req, res){
            res.render('index.ejs', {toDoList: toDoList});
        });

        app.get ("*", function(req,res){
            res.send("<h1>Invalid page</h1>");
        })
    }
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Todo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>


  <!-- As a heading -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 text-white">Todo List</span>
  </nav>
  <br><br>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group text-white bg-dark">
        <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Enter to do item</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Input a item to do list....">
        <input type="submit" class="form-control bg-primary text-white h3" >
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <br><br>
    <div class="row">
    <ul class="col-6 mx-auto" >

      <% for(let i =0; toDoList.length; i++){ %>
        <li> <%= toDoList[i] %> </li>
      <% } %>

    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the condition in looping

```
      <% for(let i =0;i < toDoList.length; i++){ %>
        <li> <%= toDoList[i] %> </li>
      <% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% for(let i =0; i<toDoList.length; i++){ %>
    <li> <%= toDoList[i] %> </li>
  <% } %>
```

use i < todoList.length. othertwise it is a infinite loop.